# Fastest way to do a non-regex refactoring for a javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refactoring, metaprogramming

Consider the following existing form in Javascript:

```
function foo(a,b,c) {
   // lots of stuff
}
```

A refactoring is needed on this code, such that each function of this form should end up like so:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', function foo(a,b,c) {
    // lots of stuff
}]
```

The prelude of the refactoring (the `foo(a,b,c)` part) is constant, so this is basically a search-and-replace job. But the hard part is finding the matching closing bracket of the function, and appending the closing square bracket to it. This is why standard search-replace in a standard text editor won't suffice. The function body is not constant.

What is the easiest way to run this refactoring on a large project with many instances of this pattern? Any reasonable tool or method is acceptable. (Command line or vim is best :))

[For anyone curious as to the scenario: the need is to make sure AngularJS injected functions are minification-safe by explicitly naming the injected parameters in the aforementioned structure]

Comment: Any decent IDE should be able to hightlight matching parenthesis?

Comment: @TGH as I'm sure you know, regex is not a strong enough tool to parse arbitrary sets of parenthesis.

Comment: Not to take the poor man's approach but couldn't this be done using some simple high level scripting?

Comment: @secretformula sure the easy way would be to hack up a Python script for this, but that is something I know how to do. I'm looking to hear what js/perl/shell/vim gurus would do :)

Comment: I guess the concern might be that if you have to write a custom parser it might be easier to just go in and make manual edits :-)

Comment: I'm working on a javascript, do you only need top-level functions refactored or also functions within functions etc?

Comment: @user1950929 these functions can appear anywhere, not just top-level, but for simplicities sake you can assume they are never nested within each other, i.e. there is never `foo(a,b,c) { foo(a,b,c) { ... }}`

Comment: @YuvalAdam: How do you identify "these function" then, are they always named "foo"? How do you distinguish them from "normal" functions? Or do you need to decide that interactively?

Comment: @bergi they are always named `foo(a,b,c)`, that is constant.

Comment: @YuvalAdam did you consider: `foo.$inject = ["a","b","c"]`?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak, no, what would that do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[esprima.org](http://esprima.org/) is a very nice JS-parser, that allows easy manipulation of code.

If you want something ready to use, then try: [ngmin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) or [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate).

Comment: These are two very interesting and relevant answers, thanks! (Though I'm still kind of curious what vim/commmand line solution there is)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, wrote some javascript to do that. I haven't tested it much, but it should work. performance is probably pretty bad though ;)

```
function refactor(code){
    var pos = 0;
    while(pos < code.length){
        console.log(pos);
        pos = code.indexOf('function foo(a,b,c)', pos);
        if(pos == -1) break;
        code = code.slice(0, pos) +  "['a', 'b', 'c', " + code.slice(pos);
        pos += 36;
        var counter = 1;
        while(counter > 0 && pos < code.length){
            var pos_next_open = code.indexOf('{', pos);
            var pos_next_close = code.indexOf('}', pos);
            if(pos_next_open > pos_next_close || pos_next_open == -1){
                --counter;
                pos = pos_next_close+1;
            } else {
                ++counter;
                pos = pos_next_open+1;
            }
        }
        code = code.slice(0, pos) +  "]" + code.slice(pos);
    }
    return code;
}
```